# Razor pass list of objects from form to controller

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, controller, razor-pages

When I try to submit form with list of objects bound in razor in controller I always receive only first 7 items. Number of items is dynamic collection[i].lenght + collection[i+1].lenght etc.

- collection[i].lenght = always 7 (days in a week)
- i = is dynamic and can be changed based on if user add/delete type
- whole collection.lenght = 7*i

I want the user to be able to edit whole collection of objects at the same time (only edit 1 field of the object). I use modal window with input. Ex: image of request -> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6b6y.png)

As can be seen from the the image I actually generate the whole request how I want it to be = 7*i
And of course if user inputed data the data is also sent.

In controller I only receive first 7 values as stated before
[image] -> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyr8u.png)

Am I missing something important why I only receive the first 7 values or is this whole process wrong and I should not be doing it like this ?

Any help would be really appriciated.

Thank you very much.

Described above -----

Answer (score 0):

First check how **FaliciltityOpeningHoursList** Bind. It not like days count of week. Because I saw there is separate list mention for days count.

please elaborate it so according we provide you solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).